# Yet another digit insertion problem

Tags: code-golf, math

Given a positive number \$n\$ we call **another** (not same as n) positive number \$m\$ good if we insert same digits in both n and m and the resulting fractional value is same.

$$m/n = m_{\text{transformed}}/n_{\text{transformed}}$$
$$or$$
$$m*n_{\text{transformed}} = m_{\text{transformed}}*n$$

Clarifications:

- No leading zeros or trailing zero insertion is allowed (you can insert 0 at beginning or end, but this must not be the last digit added in that end),other than this you can insert any digit(same digit and same number of time in both) at any place,i.e you need not insert at same place in n and m.
- At least one insertion is required.

Examples :

Example 1: $$n= 12$$

here m=66 is a good number ,we can obtain it by inserting 1 in m and n such that they become 616 and 112.

Example 2:

$$n=30$$

here m=60 is a good number, we can get 300 and 600 by inserting 0 in **middle**, as mentioned we cannot insert 0 at end or beginning, but here we inserted it in middle.

Example 3:

$$n=4$$ here 7 is a good number, as we can insert 2 and 1 , making them 124 and 217 respectively, now the fractional value is same.

Example 4:

$$n=11$$ here 2 is a good number, as we can insert 2 and 2 , making them 1221 and 222 respectively, now the fractional value is same.

Example 5:

$$n=4269$$ here 1423 is a good number, as we can insert 0, making them 42069 and 14023 respectively, now the fractional value is same.

Example 6:

$$n=1331$$ here 242 is a good number, as we can insert 2 and 2, making them 123321 and 22422 respectively, now the fractional value is same.

**Task:**

You have to find out smallest good number for a given n (there always exists a good number as pointed out by a user in comments).

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes per language wins.

Comment: If 1 digit is inserted in each, do they have to be in the same position? (ex if n=4 and m=7 is 41 and 17 a valid insertion, I know it's not a solution but just as an example)

Comment: @ophact The 3rd example (with \$124\$ and \$217\$) is a counterexample. (But I agree that it should be specified a bit more explicitly.)

Comment: @ophact  calrification's point 1 , "you can insert any digit(same digit and same number of time in both) at any place.", I will add more clarification regarding this.

Comment: A solution must always exist. Given \$n\$ choose \$m=n\times 10\$, now insert a \$1\$ at the beginning of both numbers (or really do any insertion at the same place relative to the beginning of the number).

Comment: Also, 3 is a valid solution for n=12: (12, 3) -> (1**3**2, **3**3), just helping you there

Comment: Could you provide some more test cases?

Comment: @ophact sure,done

Comment: I'd suggest that you update your testcases such that they show the *smallest* possible number rather than the current ones which are not necessarily the shortest.

Comment: So the upper bound of the digit we insert is 9, no numbers above ?

Comment: Also, when we insert 0s, sometimes the result is equivalent to adding 0s at the end, should this one not be allowed too ? For example, if we add two 0s in the middle of 10, we get 1000 which is equivalent to adding the 0s to the end

Comment: @BrockenDuck [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/265320/whats-the-difference-between-a-figure-a-number-and-a-digit) have the defination of digit, for your second query, have you read examples? Please read example 2

Comment: @OldMan For the examples you've provided, is the number you've proven to be a good number the smallest good number? If not, please change them to be so, since we need test cases.

Comment: Example 2 can be done with a smaller number : if \$n=30\$, set \$m=3\$ and insert \$1\$ at the beginning of both. \$130*3 = 13*30\$ so this value works. If have not found a smaller value, but I not sure of the result.

Comment: Sorry people, I have not added example as of smallest number because I am myself not sure if it is the correct answer, the search space is huge and I don't have a solid idea when a number can't be smallest answer..

I am thinking about changing the problem statement to reduce the search space, by limiting the number formed after insertion.

Comment: @OldMan Maybe make it such that only 1 digit insertion is allowed?

Comment: @cheems I like the idea of this challenge but I agree that the search space as currently defined makes it hard for a code-golf problem. Reposting the challenge with only 1 digit insertions would make it much more bearable, I think.

Comment: Is there an easy upper bound?

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 154 bytes

```hs
g n=head[m|m<-[1..n*10],m/=n,w<-i m,v<-i n,w*n==v*m]
i m=[read$take n s++c:drop n s|let s=show m,let l=length s,n<-[0..l],c<-"123456789"++['0'|n/=0,n/=l]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY1BCoMwFET3PUUogqBRo7W2Fv9JQhZBgxGTrxjRjXdP42Zm3sAwWrpZGeP9SBC0kgO3l@0yXuY5JiUT1BaA9OyyiVh63BYoQYAjseIRSuBbWEW7nBVB4tK0/w3bst75MmonDpxezjC@wYBROO6aOIrhhOW5EbTvsmdZvep38/m2zzTlMYsvLIDRIEYIb@WEsG4T7tFI6qpp/R8)

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 8 bytes

```javascript
n=>-~n/n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFRCoAgEAXA6yhmUfRn213E3CjkbWj02dXXmTt@saV6Pa@HHFmZFLT7HxOUpRrQjICNlhXBOdgkaFLyWOQ0GNjAWu0)

Takes \$n\$ as a BigInt. Returns 1 for \$n \ne 1\$, 2 for \$n=1\$: 1 is good with every other number.

For example, 1 is good with 2 as follows:

```
1052631578947368421 * 2 = 
2105263157894736842
```

This can be constructed by starting with the digit 1 at the top right, and doing the multiplication by 2 while copying each digit of the product up and to the left, until it finishes by arriving at a 2 with no carry.

This always works. Let \$x\$ be the number formed by the inserted digits, and \$l\$ be the number of inserted digits. Then we need \$(10x + 1)*n = n*10^l + x\$, which rearranges to \$(10n - 1)*x = n*10^l - 1\$. This always has suitable integer solutions: by [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem), \$l = \varphi(10n - 1) + 1\$ works.

However, this inserts an ending zero (which is not allowed) when \$n\$ has an ending zero. A solution is to ignore all ending zeroes of \$n\$, then put them back at the end; for example, for \$n=200\$:

```
  1052631578947368421 * 200 = 
210526315789473684200
```

Here's a function that does the full calculation, returning \$[m, n_\mathrm{transformed}, m_\mathrm{transformed}]\$:

**JavaScript, 86 bytes**

```javascript
d=(n,N=n,y=T=10n,m=-~n/n,k=m*N*T,a=y/--k+y)=>N%T?y%k>1?d(n,N,y*T):[m,a*n,a*m]:d(n,N/T)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYuxDoIwGAafhoSWv0WME/DDGzB1Mw4NoNHSrwaMSRdfvaLDLZe7h33bbVzvz5dCmOaUJs5BA4MiG64OIM/qgxLk2MtBGrIcS6VcEQV3Q2b6mLmu6qffRVEaUZ89WYkdf6n/ujQiXcOagys0aPl4QlMUEGPAFpZZL@G2Z1rrvRYifQE)